# Cannot install ArcGIS for desktop 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, installation, windows

I've checked the system requirements and meet them all. When I press SETUP (image below) a small black box will come up for a few seconds (on back left hand side of image) saying that the programme is too big to fit in memory. Ive checked how much memory I have and it is more than enough.

[image]

Comment: Please include some more information. How much memory do you have? What OS are you using? What is the exact error message? Are you installing from a CD or network install? Is there any other information that might be relevant to your case?

Comment: looking at that screenshot you have way too many applications running in the taskbar that is consuming your ram.

Comment: Sometimes it says you don't have enough space when it means that you don't have PERMISSIONS to enough space.  Does your group policy forbid installing programs?  If so you might need to talk to your supervisor.

Comment: Verify that the file you have is the same size as what you intended to download. That is a common error for incomplete/corrupted downloads.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest calling Esri Tech Support in your region. They are there to help if you are having installation problems.

http://support.esri.com/phoneSupport